# I have found a way of computing Euler's number. Is there any possible intuition of how that might be the case?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, continued-fractions, conjectures

So a few days ago I just kind of messed around with my calculator, when I had an idea about a new continued fraction. I inputted it, and I found that it converged really quickly, and, quite wondrously, converged to the base of the natural logarithm.
Then, the day later, I tried computing a similar continued fraction, this time starting with the number 2 instead of 1, without the increment of the numerator by 1.

[My first computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FKde.png)
[My second computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHP3b.png)

Interestingly, the second computation converges to EXACTLY the same values, except it's faster in the sense that the first method is delayed by 1 value per time.
Does anybody possibly have an intuition / explanation as for why this might be the case? I've looked at the general ways of computing e: the sum of integer factorials and (1+1/n)^n, which I suspect might be more relevant to this.

Comment: I feel like the first one can be rewritten as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}$ somehow. Then, the second sum is $2+\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}$, which is equivalent to the first sum.

Comment: Both are just forms of the factorial series. (Why images, not formulas?)

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the denominators get multiplied together and make factorials. I've not tried on paper, but it looks as though a bit of cancelling turns it straight into the usual series.

Answer (score 11):

Your second computation is equal to your first one:
$$1 + \frac{2+\frac{3+\frac{4+\frac{5+ \frac{\cdots}{\cdots}}{5}}{4}}{3}}{2} = 1 + \frac{2}{2} + \frac{\frac{3}{3} + \frac{\frac{4}{4} + \frac{\frac{5}{5} + \frac{\frac{6}{6} + \frac{\cdots}{\cdots}}{5}}{4}}{3}}{2} = 2 + \frac{1+\frac{1+\frac{1+\frac{1+ \frac{\cdots}{\cdots}}{5}}{4}}{3}}{2} $$

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 7):

Your first calculation can be written as

$$1+\frac12(2+\frac13(3+\frac14(4+\dots)))$$

which expands to

$$1+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{4}{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4} + \dots$$

Cancelling the repeated number in each term turns it into

$$1+\frac11+\frac1{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot 3} + \dots$$

$$=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\dots$$
$$=e$$

You've effectively factorised the series and written the result as a big fraction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Yes, I find this answer more useful than most other answers here.