# Why is Euler's number $2.71828$ and not anything else?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, irrational-numbers, eulers-number-e

Why is Euler's number $\mathtt 2.71828$ and not for example $\mathtt 3.7589$?

I know that $e$ is the base of natural logarithms. I know about areas on hyperbola `xy=1` and I know its formula: $$e =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \approx 2.71828$$
And I also know it has many other characterizations.
But, why is $e$ equal to that formula (which sum is approximately $\mathtt 2.71828$)?

I googled that many times and every time it ends in having "$e$ is the base of natural logarithms". I don't want to work out any equations using $e$ without understanding it perfectly.

**Summary:** I'm looking for the origin of $e$, if $\pi$ came from the radius of a circle with a unit diameter, then what is $e$ ???

Comment: Because that's that what the summation sums up to?...

Comment: Why is $2+2=4$?

Comment: It depends how you define $e$. If you define $e$ as the sum, then it's $2.718\dots$ because that's what the sum equals. If you define it as the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$, then it's $2.718\dots$ because that's what the limit equals.

Comment: "I don't want to work out any equations using e without understanding it perfectly."  John von Neumann, possibly one of the greatest mathematical and scientific minds of the modern era, said "In mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them."

Comment: Do you also wonder why $\pi$ is $3.1415....$?

Comment: Isn't Euler's constant $0.5772156649$?

Comment: If think Anas is asking for the origin of $e$. Clearly $\pi$ comes from the circle. And $e$? you could see it coming from the exponential function, integrating the function $1/x$, many others...

Comment: $e=1+1+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\cdots$ is greater than $1+1+\frac12 = 2.5$ and less than  $1+1+\frac1{2}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots = 3$, so you cannot have $e \le 2.5$ or $e \ge 3$.  You can do something more precise by altering these bounds and get close to its actual value

Comment: Would it be right to say your question isn't 'How is $e$ derived?" but "Why is it the size it is'? "  or maybe "Why do all these apparently different definitions all lead to the same number"?

Comment: If you haven't seen it already: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuA2EAgAegE

Comment: I don't know if this is worth expanding to an Answer, but if you prefer visual things, then I'd say "that's because it's how far to the right you have to go from x=1 to get an area under 1/x to to be 1.

Comment: Because $e$ has no special connection with the number ten, so we should expect the base ten representation of $e$ to be some crazy string of meaningless digits.

Comment: It had to be something

Comment: @Randall: There are people who have seriously proposed giving a symbol (typically τ) to a circle's circumference/radius ratio (6.283185...) instead of its circumference/diameter ratio (3.141592...).  Similarly, one could ask why the number 2.718281... gets a letter assigned to it, while its reciprocal 0.367879... doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `\mathtt` is doing there in your post, but it only affects the first digit like that. To make it affect the entire number use `{}`, or better yet, don't use `\mathtt` at all for that.

Comment: I think this is more of a mathematical-philosophy question than a maths question per se. Euler's number can be shown with many proofs to be $e\approx2.7\ldots$. The "why" behind the fact is no different to "why" any other theorem is true. We could also ask "why is the fundamental theorem of algebra true?" and I don't think you'd ever find a satisfying answer. We wouldn't know whether all maths theorems were created by the universe for some particular reason but we *can* ask whether the theorems are true. (1/2)

Comment: Theorems (such as $e\approx2.7$) can be *shown* to be true from inference from definitions and axioms. But I don't think you'd ever find a reason "why" each theorem is true other than "it is a consequence of the axioms and definitions you start with". [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13274/are-all-mathematical-theorems-necessarily-true) is a mathoverflow thread asking a similar question. (2/2)

Comment: Although your question is not crystal clear, but from going through your responses to all the threads below, it seems that what you want to know is the origin of the number: Well, if I am not mistaken, the quantity was first discovered and investigated by one of the Bernoullis (I forget which) when investigating the problem of compound interest.

Comment: @YuiToCheng $$0.5772156649\cdots$$ is the Euler-Mascheroni-constant, sometimes just called Euler's constant, whereas $$2.718281828459\cdots$$ is Euler's number (which is also the name used in the question)

Comment: Sorry, if this sound rude, but why does such a question (and its answers) receive so many upvotes ? There is no "reason" , why the sum which defines Euler's number has the given decimal expansion. This is an utterly subjective question.

Comment: One interesting thing you can do is look for why the $exp$ function defined to be the inverse of the primitive of $1/x$ that is 0 at 1, is exactly the 'real continuation' $x\mapsto e^x$, It is some work, you need the axiom of choice of course, start by considering integer powers, then rational powers, so far $x^r$ is well defined if $r$ is rational, then prove that this function admit a 'continuous extension' to the reals, then imagine how e, being itself a Cauchy sequence (or a Dedekind cut), having a transcendental power! and this should be well defined !

Answer (score 106, accepted):

$\sum\frac1{n!}$ is not that special.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is not really special.

$f'(x)=f(x)$ is a very simple differential equation, but unremarkable, really.

$\ln (x)$ is only marginally nicer than other logarithms, in that its derivative is $\frac1x$.

The fact that a **single** number connects all of these (and many, many others) as intimately as $e$ does is nothing short of a miracle. Oh, and also $e$ happens to have the decimal expansion $2.718\ldots$

Comment: Well summarized!

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}=1$, $2$ is the smallest prime, the number $n$ has $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ bits, any polynomial of real coefficients factorizes with factors of degree at most $2$, $\int_0^\pi\sin x=2$, the diagonal of a square is $\sqrt2$... So why didn't we pick $2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, you're right. $2$ is a very important mathematical constant too. I'm not saying it's a competition for which constant is best. But the number $e$ appears in so many contexts that not having a name for it is counterproductive. So therefore it has been given the name $e$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean we didn't? $2$ is a pretty important constant too!

Comment: But . . .  the second two rather straightforwardly produce the series, as a result of generating factorials, which then seems disappointingly non-miraculous. They're all linked by the factorials.

Comment: @timtfj You are right that some of these properties are easy to link together. That doesn't change my answer in the slightest. I could keep listing properties which aren't _that_ easy to link together, but that just takes time and isn't really worth it.

Comment: So maybe the real question is why sequences of reciprocals of factorials pop up all over the place.

Comment: You're right :-)

Comment: @timtfj I believe you are welcome to post such a question here in this site. Maybe someone can give you a satisfying answer.

Comment: Good point! I think it's to do with iterated prrocesses in general (taking the next derivative, choosing the next item for the permutation, dividing by the next integer, multiplying by the next bracketed expression, etc etc etc)

Comment: @timtfj $f'(x) = f(x)$ is what shows up all over the place, in one form or another.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I think they both do! I mean look at this, from somebody who accidentally calculated $e$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056044/i-have-found-a-way-of-computing-eulers-number-is-there-any-possible-intuition/3092696

Comment: @timtfj: Two words: Taylor Series.

Comment: @Dan That's what I had in mind with the taking-the-next-derivative one.

Comment: Of course if you dig deeper, you can come up with connections between these things.  For example, if you apply Euler's method with $n$ steps to find a numerical approximation to a solution to $f'(x)=f(x), f(0)=1$ then that approximate solution has $f(1)=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$.

Comment: How could one forget $\cos x + i\sin x$? (As @Dan was saying)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I am in no way claiming that this list is complete. However, these four are (I believe) the most common first encounters with $e$. $\cos x+i\sin x$ usually comes at least two or three later in my experience.

Comment: So, is it special that $e$'s decimal digits starts with a repeated $4$-digit block? (I know it's a coincidence but it's really curious given that we didn't cherry-pick the base and the number.)

Comment: @user21820 What's even more special is that that four-digit block coincides with the birth year of Henrik Ibsen, favourite playwright of Norwegian teachers everywhere (most people will have heard "In the hall of the Mountain King", a piece written by Edvard Grieg to one of Ibsen's plays). Other than that it's not of any significance that I know of.

Comment: @Arthur: Nah let's stick to mere mathematics. In 1828, Gauss proved his Theorema Egregium (remarkable theorem). That same year was the only year Gauss attended a scientific conference, or so it has been said. More seriously, [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605706/21820) explores possible mathematical explanations of this phenomenon, and [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/eApproximations.html) says that $(1+9^{-4^{7.6}})^{3^{2^{85}}} ≈ e$ with $18457734525360901453873570$ decimal digits of precision!!!

Comment: @user21820 Sure, but you can't ask "What's the connection between Gauss and $e$?" at a bar quiz. There are too many to count. You can, however, ask "What's the connection between Ibsen and $e$?" (at least if it has a sciency theme, and it's held in Norway).

Comment: I didn’t meant to critique you. I realize now it came across that way. I’m so sorry my friend $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Arthur: Haha. And I just realized that the approximation was a trivial one. So silly to not notice it was an instance of the standard limit.

Comment: @user21820: If those 4 digits repeated forever, we arrive at the rational approximation 271801/99990.  But I don't see any obvious significance to this number.

Comment: @Dan: Was it not obvious enough that I know that?

Comment: While we're on coincidences of digits, there are an awful lot of $2$-digit multiples of $9$ near the beginning. I'll put them in bold and remove the decimal point. **27,18,** 28, **18**, 28 ,**45,90,45,** 235, **36**, 02874. . . (I don't think the $36$ really counts but I've included it for compleeness. )

Comment: Also every group of digits in between those, and the group just after the 36,
adds to 10. (28, 28, 235, 028) Then 11 for the 74. This is reminding me a bit of "schizophrenic numbers", which are irrational but have outbreaks of recurring digits every so often.

Comment: @Yves Daoust $2^x$ satisfies the difference equation $\Delta f(x)=f(x)$, a finite-difference version of $f'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: You missed that the only real number $a$ which satisfies $a^x \ge 1+x$ for all real numbers $x$ is $a=e.$ I find this by far the most magical among elementary properties of $e.$ Among more appealing properties of $e$ lies the central limit theorem which relates to the Euler's number via the density of the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @AdityaGuhaRoy I never claimed my list was complete. I do, however, believe that these are the most common textbook definitions of $e$. So no, I don't think I missed your two contributions. They are cool, but I don't think they belong.

Comment: AH okay, got your point. Definitely these are well-known and as I expected you knew them, along with Euler's formula.

Answer (score 29):

We use $e$ because it a natural choice, as it yields a simple derivative:

$$(e^x)'=e^x.$$

For other bases, we have

$$(a^x)'=\ln a\,a^x$$ and the factor $\ln a$ is annoying.

For a very similar reason we use radians in the trigonometric functions:

$$(\sin x)'=\cos x.$$

With degrees, we would have

$$(\sin_d x)'=\frac\pi{180}\cos_d x,$$ once more an embarrassing factor.

As shown by Hyperion, the condition $(e^x)'=e^x$ induces the value

$$1+1+\frac12+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\cdots$$

---

Assume you wanted to find a number $b$ such that $(b^x)'=b^x$. Using the definition of the derivative, you could try to solve

$$\frac{b^{x+h}-b^x}h\approx b^x$$
where $h$ is a small increment.

Then
$$\frac{b^{x+h}-b^x}h=b^x\frac{b^h-1}h\approx b^x$$
leads to

$$b^h\approx 1+h$$ or $$b\approx(1+h)^{1/h}.$$

It turns out that this expression has a limit for $h\to0$, which you can obtain using the generalized binomial theorem.

E.g.,

$$1.000001^{1000000}=2.718280469\cdots$$

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, one answer is "because that's the value that the various definitions produce, and when we follow them $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ pops out". But it's not a very satisfying answer (in fact I think you're asking for an underlying reason why that happens).

I can't give a definitive *why,* but my suggestion is that it's something to do with iterated processes like

- taking the next derivative
- dividing by the next integer
- choosing the next item in a permutation
- multiplying by the next bracketed expression

all of which are quite good at producing sequences of factorials.

But of course I've now got $e^{iπ}=-1$ nagging at me, and even though that can be explained in terms of "exponential growth sideways" and proved to be true, it doesn't in itself seem *that* related to any iterated process, and @Arthur's comment that it's "nothing short of miraculous" seems more accurate than any proof of the connection would be.

My suggested explanation, if true, just pushes the question back a level: "Why do iterated processes that produce the series for $e$ pop up all over the place?"

Typically if you ask *Why?* more than about four or maybe five times (following underlying reasons rather than a chain of trivial causal events or a string of theorems), you'll get to unanswerable philosophical questions—for instance "Why is it raining?" leads me after a few steps to "why is there such a thing as the laws of physics?" I suspect that pursuing the reasons why a particular number is as it is will have the same result.

Comment: How do you not see exponential growth as an iterative process, given the standard definition of exponentiation as repeated multiplication of the same number?

Comment: @Nij I do, but I mean that $e^{iπ}=-1$ doesn't intuitively seem like an example of it—it looks more like an amazing static relationship between $π$, $i$ and $e$ which can be *proved* by talking about exponential growth but is really a free-standing thing of its own.

Comment: @timtfj But Euler's identity (of which the equation above is only a product) is related to an iterative process, namely that of repeatedly multiplying an arbitrary complex number by some complex $z.$

Comment: @Allawonder of course, but the point is that it's not necessarily intuitive to see it that way—in fact some people struggle hard to. The problem is that *logic* of the situation seems to be at a surface level, distinct from the level of the **WHY???** that people are asking themselves. As though the logical explanation amounts to the mere mechanics of something, or to describing the features of something that already exists rather than explaining why it exists. I think it's really a subjective or philosophical issue, not a mathematical one.

Comment: @timtfj I wasn't trying to explain why $e$ appears to be connected with iterated operations; I was only pointing out that contrary to what you thought, the complex exponential defines one of the most intuitive iterative operations.

Comment: @Allawonder I agree with that—and actually it *is* intuitive once you think of complex multiplication as rotation. Which also makes $\cos x+i\sin x$ intuitive. And $π$ is just half way round the circle, to $-1$.

Comment: Exactly. BTW I think your answer is closest to what OP actually wanted to know. Please keep it up.

Comment: @Allawonder Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> Why is Euler's number 2.718 and not anything else?

Short answer: **by definition** so.

First paragraph of the Wikipedia article [$e$ (mathematical constant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)):

The number $e$ is a mathematical constant that is the base of the natural logarithm: the unique number whose natural logarithm is equal to one. It is approximately equal to $2.71828$, and is the limit of $(1 + 1/n)^n$ as $n$ approaches infinity, an expression that arises in the study of compound interest.

> ... why is $e$ equal to that formula (which sum is approximately $.71828$)?

"That formula" is one of the equivalent **definitions** of the constant $e$. All the equivalent definitions has the same approximate value $.71828$.

> I googled that many times and every time it ends in having "e is the base of natural logarithms". I don't want to work out any equations using e without understanding it perfectly.

Should you have any similar question in the future, the first thing you should ask is what is the **definition** of the mathematical object that you are confused about.

---

For history of the constant $e$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History

---

[Added to respond to a comment below.]

The way you phrase your question is problematic. The constant $e$ is not *discovered* by mathematicians. It is *defined* to be the constant $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, which has the approximate value $2.71828$. What mathematician do is nothing but give an interesting constant a name. If Bob calls his dog "Alpha", it does not make much sense to ask "Why is Alpha a dog, not a cat?" --- because Bobs calls his dog "Alpha"!

On the other hand, it is reasonable to ask what the "story" about $e$ is, where it appears and why it is interesting. I believe this is what you really wanted to ask.

You may want to take a look at this article:

[An Intuitive Guide To Exponential Functions $\&$ $e$](https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-guide-to-exponential-functions-e/)

Here is an excerpt:

> Describing e as “a constant approximately 2.71828…” is like calling pi “an irrational number, approximately equal to 3.1415…”. Sure, it’s true, but you completely missed the point.
>
> Pi is the ratio between circumference and diameter shared by all circles. It is a fundamental ratio inherent in all circles and therefore impacts any calculation of circumference, area, volume, and surface area for circles, spheres, cylinders, and so on. Pi is important and shows all circles are related, not to mention the trigonometric functions derived from circles (sin, cos, tan).
>
> e is the base rate of growth shared by all continually growing processes. e lets you take a simple growth rate (where all change happens at the end of the year) and find the impact of compound, continuous growth, where every nanosecond (or faster) you are growing just a little bit.
>
> e shows up whenever systems grow exponentially and continuously: population, radioactive decay, interest calculations, and more. Even jagged systems that don’t grow smoothly can be approximated by e.

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head. Such a question would rather fit on a philosophy-site.

Comment: Thank you very much, but as mentioned above (in the question) : "I googled that many times", I (of course) have seen Wikipedia's article about $e$ (which you shared above), and it doesn't help me to recognize the origin of $e$. I think the mathematicians found out the metioned things on Wikipedia **AFTER** discovering $e$. so, I'm looking for what they were searching for before finding $e$.

Comment: @anaspcpro: You asked an interesting topic in a confusing way. **NOT AT ALL** "after", please read the History part of the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History

Answer (score 3):

No, the reason is that putting 1 dollar to bank with 100% interest rate you will get 2 dollars after 1 year. That is very simple and it is about constant 2.

But, if you will want more, you will put there your dollar for half a year, you will get 1.5 dollar, then you will put this amount to bank again and after another half a year you will have 2.25 dollars.

Increasing the frequency of put - get you will end up with 2.718...$ which is the constant e.

Also notice that exp'(0) == 1 x'(0) == 1 i.e. at 0 they have the same growth.

Comment: Good example. Though this is not how real banks calculate real interest (they know what will happen if they calculated fractional year interest like you suggested)

Comment: @lalala most banks I know of calculate fractional year interest, typically 1/12, 1/4, or 1/2 of a year depending on the account type. Some accounts only pay interest annually, but in my experience, monthly or quarterly are the most common.

Comment: Please understand that e is about infinitesimal linear growth with slope 1.

Comment: Please understand that e is result of infinitesimal linear growth with slope 1 on interval [0;1]. An example of this is the bank account mentioned above. All definitions using series or logarithms are mathematically correct but not direct.

Comment: This is another characterization for $e$ which I've found on Wikipedia, but didn't help so much....

Answer (score 2):

We can derive that formula through the use of Maclaurin series. If you are unsure of what a Maclaurin series is at this moment of time, it a a method of representing any function in a certain interval as an 'infinite polynomial'. The general formula for the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = e^x$ is
$$f(x) = e^x = f(0) + f'(0)x + f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!} + f''(0)\frac{x^3}{3!} + ...$$
Because the derivative of $e^x$  is equal to itself, plugging in $1$ to the infinite series, we find that 
$$e^1 = e = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ...$$

Comment: This is a proof for the formula which doesn't answer my question

Comment: @anaspcpro you asked why $e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$, and I showed you where it is derived from.

Comment: yes, but, what I was searching for is "what was mathematicians searching for and brought up e ????"

Comment: @Arthur showed what I was looking for...
and your answer helped me understand what he said :).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @anaspcpro That wasn't _at all_ obvious from your question. Could you edit your question to make it clearer? "What were mathematicians searching for when they 'invented' e?" is a completely different question to "Why is e=2.718...?"

Comment: @anaspcpro Hmmm that's not what your question translated to me, but the important this is that you got your question answered by any one of us.

Comment: @Hyperion, I found many interesting answer after posting the question, all of them defined $e$ for what it is famous for, likely I didn't get the origin of e in any answer. The question is "what was the mathematicians searching for and finally found $e$ ???"

Answer (score 0):

One introduction of $e$ can be seen as a solution to $f'(x)=f(x)$. Indeed with $\lambda$ any constant, the function
$$ f \ : \ x \mapsto \lambda e^x$$ 
is so that at each point, its "increase" equals its value, hence $f'(x)=f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

For example, because the equally perplexing expansions

$$\cos x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}  = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots $$
$$\sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \ldots$$

are linked by

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$

and they all hold too when $x=-i$, leading to your formula when you insert the first two in the third one. When $x=\pi$ you have the beautiful [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity): $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

So, in this sense, your question is an understated invitation to contemplate an apparition of [mathematical beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty) and the uses of it.

Attaching numerical estimates to these constructs is a possibility that would be unreasonable to dismiss a priori, for [quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification_(science)) is a fundamental method of enquiry and, after all, of finding our our own way in this world.
The answer to the question 'what is this?' is completed by the answer to the question 'how much is this?'.

It may take a long time before the penny drops, but the simplicity of some formulas may be flabbergasting on second thoughts. By no chance, by the way, [transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) such [$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) have attracted the attribution [trascendental](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/transcendental).

Proceed safely and keep on wondering.

---

Approaching your question

> Why is Euler's number 2.71828 and not for example 3.7589?

more literally, the definition of $e$ you quote also reveals the structure of this number (something some numbers do not seem to have, so plain are they). Since a number is made of digits, I have compiled a table where you can see which terms in the expansion contribute to each digit of $e$, restricting myself to the first 8 decimal digits. So you can see the process by which summing successive terms adds information the value of $e$. The tabulation is not entirely foolproof, subject to false negatives occurring, but gives an idea.

[image]

Reconnecting to the first part of this answer, I like to picture to myself that the 2 in $e$ is bred by $\cos 0 = 1$ and $-i^2=1$ (a trigonometry because and a complex-number because) and this cannot sum up to 3 (the arithmetics because). 
One can $\infty$-ly keep on elaborating on these lines and add more and more layers of considerations as you go.