# Why is $\ln 20$ so close to $3$?

Tags: logarithms, approximation

\I understand that it can be just a coincidence, but maybe there is a reason?

The closest I could find is using the property that $\log_2 x \approx \ln x + \log_{10}x$ and approximate values of $\log_2 10 \approx 3.3$ and $\log_{10}2 \approx 0.3$. Is there a better explanation?

Comment: $\ln(20) \approx 2.99573227...$. Well, this is because $e^3$ is "close" to $20$.

Comment: Yours is effectively the same question as [Why is $e=2.718$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092340) and I've not yet seen a more satisfying or deep answer than "because that is its decimal expansion".

Answer (score 2):

Using the [software program `ries`](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html) I easily found that 
$$e^\pi-\pi \approx 19.999099979 \approx 20$$
 which I think is more accurate and  interesting than
 $$ e^3 \approx 20.085536923 \approx 20.$$
The approximation with $\pi$ is already known and is
asked about in [MSE question 724872](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/724872) (Thanks 
to a comment by user 'Jam').

Note: Here is output from `ries 2.99573227355399099`:

```
Your target value: T = 2.99573227355399                       mrob.com/ries

                      x = 3                      for x = T + 0.00426773  {30}
                   x-pi = 1/-7                   for x = T + 0.00300324  {66}
            sqrt(ln(x)) = pi/3                   for x = T - 0.00169507  {71}
                    e x = 5+pi                   for x = T - 0.000607718 {70}
               log_5(x) = 1-1/pi                 for x = T - 0.000152139 {77}
                    e^x = 4*5                    ('exact' match)         {65}
               (3"/x)^2 = 1/ln(phi)              for x = T - 5.12827e-05 {84}
                 e^x+pi = e^pi                   for x = T - 4.50021e-05 {73}
               1/(pi-x) = phi^4                  for x = T - 3.76537e-05 {87}
              sqrt(e^x) = 2 sqrt(5)              for x = T + 4.44089e-16 {80}
  (Stopping now because best match is within 2.66e-15 of target value.)
```

Note: You may be interested in the following
$$ e^{\pi\sqrt{22}} \approx 2508951.99 $$
$$ e^{\pi\sqrt{37}} \approx 199148674.9999 $$
$$ e^{\pi\sqrt{58}} \approx 24591257751.999999822 $$
which have a satisfying explanation.
The biggest of these seems to be
$$ e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} \approx
262537412640768743.99999999999925 $$
For details read the Wikipedia [Heegner number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number)
article.

Comment: The first approximation is covered in [question 724872](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724872/why-is-e-pi-pi-so-close-to-20).

Comment: @jam Thanks for that interesting comment!

Comment: You're very welcome. Also, the $e^{\pi\sqrt{n}}$ numbers you list are called ["class 2 numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Class_2_numbers) (https://oeis.org/A005847) and are related to the Heegner numbers, e.g. $e^{\pi\sqrt{169}}\approx 640320^3+744-10^{-12}$. Unlike the OP's original approximation, I think these ones actually do have a satisfying deeper meaning.

Comment: @jam Thanks for that interesting comment! Yes, I already knew that, In contrast to $e^3\approx 20$ these have satisfying meaning.

Comment: [This specific comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1598982/741874) answers, among other things, my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because $e^3\approx 20.086$ is close to $20$, or alternately, because $\sqrt[3]{20}\approx 2.714$ is close to $e$.